# Are there any 5.1 surround audio switches on the market?

Tags: audio, product-rec, switch, speakers, surround-sound

(Somewhat related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/77385/hook-two-computers-to-one-speaker))

I have a set of Logitech 5.1 surround speakers, which use three stereo 3.5mm TRS connectors (minijacks) to transfer the audio (the typical green/black/orange audio outputs). I have a [Griffin Firewave](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/firewave) hooked up to my MacBook Pro, and my desktop has a [Realtek ALC889](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=28&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=173) audio chipset. I have looked for a way to, essentially, switch the speaker inputs between my Firewave and my desktop without having to disconnect the cables from one, route them around my desk, and plug them into the other.

I'd love to have something like an old Belkin DB-25/LPT switch, but for these audio cables.

[image]

Of course, purchasing one and soldering my own cables on the connection terminals is always an option, but, **is there a reasonably priced 5.1 audio switch (or 3x stereo) on the market that will accomplish the simple task of switching audio outputs between two computers into a set of 5.1 speakers?**

Comment: you might try asking on http://home4film.com/ or http://hookitupright.com/ -- both sites use the same Q-n-A format this site does, and both focus on home theater questions.  i think it's an OK question for this site, since you're asking about a switch to connect two computers to one set of speakers, but those other sites seem like good additional resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple stereo, some kvm switches will do audio.  For full 5.1, you're usually looking at something like a full stereo receiver, and that's probably gonna run a lot more than you want to spend.

Comment: as long as it's the 3x-stereo-connection style 5.1 (analog), a switch is doable, at least as a DIY project.  if it's digital 5.1 (coax or optical), yeah, you probably need a full receiver.

Comment: Wouldn't a stereo receiver imply that it's 2 channel audio? I think you need a surround receiver for 5.1.